# Load HDF5 in Excel?

Tags: excel, hdf5, hdf

Is there a way to load/import an HDF5 file (sometimes called H5, HD5, or Hierarchical Data Format) in to Excel?

I do not want to export an intermediary CSV file, as ideally I would like to modify the data and in Excel and resave back to HDF5 (but an acceptable answer is one that solves the problem of loading the file first).

Note that HDF5 is the format used by Python's PyTables, pandas, and h5py (experts in these packages may be able to answer this question). However I would prefer not to use Python to solve this problem (I would prefer an existing software tool). Maybe there is a way with ODBC...but I don't know how.

Comment: Why would you not also count python as an "existing software tool"?  In 2 or 3 lines of python/pandas you can convert from hdf5 to excel and vice versa (just see documentation).  I'm not sure what you are looking for that is going to be any better than that but maybe you can elaborate.  Maybe there is an ODBC way though, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Although I do know Python, I am looking for a solution to give to non-Python users who only know how to use Excel. Furthermore, when an HDF5 file contains more than one dataset, multiple groups, and various datatypes it becomes tedious (more than 3 lines I'd expect) to write a Python script that is capable of handling any HDF5 file thrown at it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PyHexad Excel add-in for HDF5**

https://www.hdfgroup.org/2015/06/america-runs-on-excel-and-hdf5/